# what folders and files in module is reason for creating tables in database?

Tags: magento2, database, module, sql

I saw one module folders and files in magento connect. in that only **etc, Helper, & Module** folder is present.

but there is no **sql** folder. but still that module created a text box in backend , so  that we can enter the zip codes in textfield and its going to be save in database.

so what is the reason behind that table. also how to find what is name of table craeted by that module ?

[image]

Comment: hi, here is created in XML file for the config layout. under the etc folder and data maintain by this file. for system config layout no need to create any phtml file

Comment: how to find what is name of table created by that module ?

Comment: no need to table its. its store the value in xml

Comment: @raphael is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't necessarily need sql install/upgrade scripts to have variables stored in the database.

Creating fields for a module under `etc/system.xml` will let people save variables in the `core_config_data` database table without the need of a `sql` folder.

Comment: how to find what is name of table created by that module ?

Comment: @user492664463 as I said the module has not created any table it simply uses the native `core_config_data` Magento database table

Comment: in this module i mentioned in question, if we enter thousand of zip codes, will it save in core_config_data ?

Comment: @user492664463 yes it will

Comment: until the maximum length of the `TEXT` column is reached (about 64K)